# How do i sort by groups?

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

I have this class:

```
class Model:
    name = None
    price = None
```

And plain array of `Model` instances like this:

```
name ; price
BMW 4-series ; 90
BMW Z4 ; 190
BMW X5 ; 220
Lamborghini Miura ; 910
Ferrari 458 Italia ; 580
Ferrari California T ; 530
```

And so on.. I need to sort this array in two ways: firstly, by brand (so, BMW items come first) and then by price, without removing previous effect.

Problem is that if i do `sort()` to sort by `name` attribute, and then by `price`, first sort effect will be lost. What should i do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sort your object list using [**`operator.attrgetter`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter)

```
from operator import attrgetter

m1 = Model(name='Lamborghini Miura', price=910)
m2 = Model(name='Ferrari 458 Italia', price=580)
lst = [m1, m2]

lst.sort(key=attrgetter('name', 'price'))
```

Comment: I actually didn't know you could specify more than one argument to the `...getter`s

Comment: @AdamSmith yes. Also I think  `attrgetter` is a bit faster.

Comment: It certainly IS faster.

Answer (score 5):

all the `sort` functions take an optional kwarg `key`. It can be used in conjunction with the fact that tuples sort this way naturally to build an anonymous `lambda` function like so:

```
lst = [Model(name='BMW 4-series',price=90), ... ]
lst.sort(key=lambda m: (m.name, m.price))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the operator module:

```
from operator import attrgetter

model1 = Model('BMW Z4', 190)
model2 = Model('BMW X5', 220)
obj_list = [model1, model2)

sorted(obj_list, key=attrgetter('name', 'price'))
```

See: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Operator_Module_Functions